# Is there a way to log changes in Jenkins server configuration?

Tags: jenkins, logging, audit

I'm looking for something like the [Job Config history plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory/) but to log the changes in the Jenkins server itself (any change under the /manage section or credentials).

I tested the [Audit Trail plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/audit-trail/), but it only logs who and when, but nothing about the content of the change.

I'm using the roles based strategy, so there is a reduced group of people able to do changes, but I still need more precise information.

Answer (score 1):

Job Config History Plugin also tracks system configuration. Just click on *Job Config History* (on the left-side menu) on the main dashboard (outside of any job). When there, you can see all server configuration changes with all features like diffs and raw XML access.